# How to train single data present in a data set to a already trained neural network?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, neural-network, python-3.5

I already have a neural network that is trained,

```
clf = neural_network.MLPClassifier(
        activation='relu',
        hidden_layer_sizes=(40,40,40,40),
        learning_rate='adaptive',
        learning_rate_init=0.01,
        solver='sgd',
        alpha=1e-6,
        max_iter=20000,
        warm_start=True,
)
```

I have trained it,

```
clf.fit(X,Y)
```

This classifier has two classes `[0,1]`.

Now when i train it further by using one data from data set at a time.
    clf.fit([features_1],[1])
The error pops up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    fav_clf.fit(X_, Y)
  File "D:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py", line 973, in fit    
hasattr(self, "classes_")))
  File "D:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py", line 331, in _fit
X, y = self._validate_input(X, y, incremental)
  File "D:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py", line 924, in _validate_input
(self.classes_, classes))
ValueError: warm_start can only be used where `y` has the same classes as in the previous call to fit. Previously got [0 1], `y` has [1]
```

Comment: You cannot call `fit()` with only a single sample. Use `partial_fit()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about `warm_start` for a minute, and try to understand the [usage of `fit()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.fit).

> ```
> fit(X, y):
>     Fit the model to data matrix X and target(s) y.
> ```

So the model cannot learn anything if you provide the data for only a single class. `warm_start` in MLPClassifier is used to:

> reuse the solution of the previous call to fit as initialization

So, the training can be faster, weights from previous training will be used as initial weights, but it will still need to access multiple classes data to be able to differentiate between them.

Now seeing your question, I think you want to use the model as an [incremental classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning):-

> Actually, the ability to learn incrementally from a mini-batch of
>   instances (sometimes called “online learning”). All estimators
>   implementing the partial_fit API are candidates.

So if you just want the model to incrementally learn the newer data, you need to do `partial_fit()`. But note that you will have to turn `warm_start = False`, to use `partial_fit()`.

```
# First call to partial_fit
clf.partial_fit(X, Y, classes=[0, 1])

# All next calls
clf.partial_fit(X, Y)    #<==  Here you can pass a single sample.
```

Comment: Well Problem solved and also created another Warning (from warnings module):
  File "D:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py", line 927
    if np.setdiff1d(classes, self.classes_, assume_unique=True):
DeprecationWarning: The truth value of an empty array is ambiguous. Returning False, but in future this will result in an error. Use `array.size > 0` to check that an array is not empty.    Please Suggest directions

Comment: Sometimes i get same results(bug) and sometimes expected results. Note:Using StandardScaler

Comment: @Nikhil About the warning: Its coming from numpy and nothing to worry. Next scikit version will handle it appropriately.

Comment: @Nikhil About the bug (same results), I will need more info:- Complete code, and some data samples to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am trying to classify music on basis user will like it[1] or not[0]. Sometimes i get only zeros or ones

Comment: y, sr = librosa.load(audio_root+'/'+temp[0], offset=30, duration=20);X.append(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr).flatten());scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X);X_ = scaler.transform(X);fav_clf.partial_fit(X_, Y, classes=[0,1])

Comment: Atleast can you help me remove the empty array as reported by the error, I have tried finding it by `if len(subarray)==0:print('Found')`, But No luck Nothing

Comment: @Nikhil No.Its nothing related to your data. Its inside the source code of scikit. You dont need to and cannot do anything about it, except just hiding the warning.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your help, but am I doing it right, say I am trying to classify music